# Is there a way to error out Power BI export when filters are invalid

Tags: powerbi

We are exporting a Power BI report. The code looks something like that:

```
{
  "format": "PDF",
  "powerBIReportConfiguration": {
    "reportLevelFilters": [
      {
        "filter": "Contract/Vertical eq 'Manufacturing'"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the issue -- if the filter is invalid, we get back all data instead of the report erroring out.

This is a problem since if, in the future, somebody makes breaking changes to the report model, and the filter becomes invalid, we will be sending incorrect data to the users, which is much worse than if the scheduled export errored out.

Is there a way to tell Power BI API to error out a report export if filters are invalid?